# How to delete all data in a partition?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a CosmosDB collection with a number of different partitions.  I want to delete all of the data in one of the partitions so I tried to run the command:

```
db.myCollection.deleteAll({PartitionKey: 'pop-9q'})
```

Where `PartitionKey` is the field that I partition/shard based on.  But when I execute this it returns the not very helpful message:

> ERROR: An Error has occurred

Why would I be getting this message and how can I either get more details on the cause or find a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, at this time, you are unable to perform a bulk delete. Please Up Vote and Comment on this functionality: [Add the ability to delete ALL data in a partition](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17296813-add-the-ability-to-delete-all-data-in-a-partition)

Additionally, which  API are you consuming? For Gremlin API you could execute something like the following:  g.V().drop()

Comment: It looks like it's Mongo

Comment: yeah it's Mongo.  So how would I go about deleting the data in a partition?

Comment: Yes, vote it up in the CosmosDB User Voice and wait for five years to see it as "Planned"... hahahahahaha (Just look at the SKIP clause feature request, for example)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: g.V().drop() will drop all vertices in the graph regardless of the partition. 

Please refrain from using this as will delete your entire graph database, unless that was the original intention.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos SDK has added this ability - currently only available as a preview feature (which requires you to opt-in via the portal)
See here for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-delete-by-partition-key?tabs=dotnet-example

Sample code included there:

```
// Get reference to the container
var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("DatabaseName", "ContainerName");

// Delete by logical partition key
ResponseMessage deleteResponse = await container.DeleteAllItemsByPartitionKeyStreamAsync(new PartitionKey("Contoso"));

 if (deleteResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Delete all documents with partition key operation has successfully started");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike said, a "delete all data" feature is not supported yet in Cosmos db SQL API and Mongo API. I notice that you have already added comments in above [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17296813-add-the-ability-to-delete-all-data-in-a-partition). I just provide you with a workaround here that using bulk delete stored procedure for Cosmos db SQL API.

(sample code: https://gist.github.com/deepumi/2a23c5380202bddf0b85e83baf5833be)

For Mongo API, unfortunately, even stored procedure is not supported. You could create an [Azure HTTP Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) to execute bulk delete code in the function whenever you want or merge it into your program code.

Answer (score 0):

For GremlinAPI, you can do the following:

1. Make sure that you have a property `partitionKey` directly on the vertex as well as the edge. if you do not have one, then just add the property to all vertices and edges.
2. set the property correctly, every time you insert either a vertex or an edge along with setting the partition key for your CosmosDB container.

to delete all data from the above partition, simple do the following:

```
g.V().has('partitionKey', 'yourPartitionKey').drop()
```

this will ensure that only those vertices that have the `yourPartitionKey` value for the `partitionKey` property will be deleted.

Since Gremlin ensures that there are no dangling edges when a vertex is deleted, all the edges will be automatically deleted as well.